# Magento2: Product import errors

Tags: magento2, importexport, product-import

I am getting errors while import products.

I have downloaded sample files and trying to upload the same on the website. But getting errors.

```
Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set doesn't exist?) in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: Check your Attribute set exists or not which you added in CSV sheet to import

Comment: Please let me know which table we can check the attribute set? @TejaBhagavanKollepara

Comment: No need to check the any table. Check once in csv sheet and compare the attribute set name which you added in field with admin > stores > attribute set. If those two are same then no problem

Comment: I have checked same attribute added in the datasheet but still getting error. @TejaBhagavanKollepara

Comment: Errors getting when uploading new products.

Comment: Not attribute. I told attribute set name

Comment: Can you check my sample CSV file? Please let me know what missing there. @TejaBhagavanKollepara

Comment: Yeah sure. send me on teja.bhagavan1@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104121/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check once the attribute set which you added in CSV and compare with the attribute set which you want to assign the products in admin
2. By going to admin > stores > attribute set, you can find the attribute set name
3. copy and paste the desired attribute set id name in CSV file then try.

Please let me know if you find any issues. Then it will be clear all of your error.

Comment: The issue is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure!
It seems some missing attribute set name.

You need to change the column value of the attribute set. whichever is your CSV file. and the rows are 1,2,3,4,5,6.
It means you mentioned the wrong attribute set name or you mentioned attribute set name which does not exist in your store.

I hope then it works!

Answer (score 0):

To import products through Magento Default Import Process, "attribute_set_code" is a required entity to define in sheet(CSV) with valid value. In most cases the value of it could be "Default" but check it from Admin -- Store -- Attributes -- Attribute Set and make sure you opt the correct on which you are going to create products.